# What does `/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" <SOME_PATH>` mean?

Tags: cmake

Could anyone help explain what `/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" <SOME_PATH>` means? I couldn't find the description of `cmake_depends` on [cmake.org](https://cmake.org)...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-E` is the command line mode. But there is no `cmake_depends`, so I assume it is an error. Can you give some context or the source? Documentation concerning -E: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode

Comment: I encounter that line of code when I was compiling [Caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) using `cmake`. After running `cmake`, that line of code was in some generated file. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/EasonD3/2cf025def7ccb0125f8fecf4cb1ff866#file-build-make-L66. Based on that, I was wondering if `cmake_depends` is some option of `cmake`...

Comment: Ok, it can be, that this is not documented, as not meant to be used by users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `cmake_depends` is not documented in the documentation, I would call it an internal interface, that should not be used by users. If you use it, it might fail with any new version without any warning or deprecation period.

Grepping through CMake's source code reveals the following comments, which might help you.

CMake/Source/cmMakefileTargetGenerator.cxx:

```
// Generate a call this signature:
//
//   cmake -E cmake_depends <generator>
//                          <home-src-dir> <start-src-dir>
//                          <home-out-dir> <start-out-dir>
//                          <dep-info> --color=$(COLOR)
//
// This gives the dependency scanner enough information to recreate
```

CMake/Source/cmcmd.cxx:

```
// Full signature:
//
//   -E cmake_depends <generator>
//                    <home-src-dir> <start-src-dir>
//                    <home-out-dir> <start-out-dir>
//                    <dep-info> [--color=$(COLOR)]
...
// Support older signature for existing makefiles:
//
//   -E cmake_depends <generator>
//                    <home-out-dir> <start-out-dir>
//                    <dep-info>
//
// Just pretend the source directories are the same as the
// binary directories so at least scanning will work.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After `cmake ..`, `make` and `make install`, will the paths listed after `cmake_depends` be permanently added to some system environment variable(s)? For my case, after cmaking Caffe, I can successfully import Caffe in another project by running `find_package(Caffe)`, without setting `Caffe_DIR`. So I was wondering if `cmake -E cmake_depends` has already set the Caffe path permanently somewhere.

Comment: No, CMake does not add anything to path variables. But your `make install` moves the libraries and headers to locations, where CMake will look by default.